# Search page isn't returning any results

Tags: search

I've looked around and can't figure out what happened to my search page. It used to work but then I guess why I added my archives.php and a bunch of other things it stopped working, but I can't tell at what point in the last week it stopped working.I usually test almost everything on the site when I make changes but for some reason I didn't check the search function until near the end and then it was too late. [This is the site.](http://averylawoffice.ca)

```
        <div id="main">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'toolbox' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>



            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'search' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'toolbox' ); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search terms. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'toolbox' ); ?></p>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            </article><!-- #post-0 -->

        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #main -->
```

And of course I have my php opening and closing tags, header & footer. I just didn't want to add everything.

Currently, if you search for a word that you know is somewhere in the site it returns a NOTHING FOUND. I believe it's to do with my get_template_part as I don't quite understand the wordpress codex for it.

```
<?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'search' ); ?>
```

If I use

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'search' ); ?>
```

It returns with an error

[image]

Which I have no clue what it means.

What could be making the search function behave like this? It used to work.
Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Toolbox
 */
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'toolbox' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">Posted on: <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

Comment: Can you paste the first 5 lines of the file "content.php" in your toolbox theme?

Comment: Yep. See updated question.

Comment: You didn't close your php tag after your comment. Add a `?>` on line 5 before your `<article>`

Comment: Thanks. I'll be sure to watch for simple mistakes like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the closing `?>` php tag before the `<article>` tag.